# Showing Keyboard causes the cell row containing active text field hides under its section footer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, keyboard

I just successfully set up content inset adjustment to make visible, dealing with the keyboard of iPhone, of the active text field on a cell row managed by a tableViewController (dynamic table view and different custom cell types - some from XIB and others from code). Well... almost success; except for the below issue:
 a section footer doesn't move up the same extent of the rows of the section so that often the footer makes the active text field invisible. A user has to scroll the table view a bit to show the row with the active text field (strangely the footer stays floating above the rows in scrolling).

Anyone has seen such weird thing before? Is it the section footer moving with the section rows together as an integral unit? How can the footer stay floating above the scrolling rows of the section? Please shed me some light and I even don't know where/how to start debugging such issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks for editing my post. After many hours of struggling, I finally find the reason from reading pages of Apple document, which is of enum UITableView.Style having two cases:

.plain : Section headers and footers are displayed as inline separators and **float** when the table view is scrolled.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/plain

.grouped: Section headers and footers do **not float** when the table view scrolls.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/grouped

Apple should rename the enum to HeaderFooterStyle instead to make our finding easier (another example of clarity over brevity)

I hope someone else bumping into the headache might find the post useful.